# Can compare return anything else than -1, 0 and 1?

Tags: compare, comparison, ocaml

The [docs for the `Pervasives.compare` function](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.03/libref/Pervasives.html#VALcompare) state that

> `compare x y` returns `0` if `x` is equal to `y`, a negative integer if `x` is less than `y`, and a positive integer if `x` is greater than `y`.

This suggests it can return *any* negative or positive integer, not just `-1` or `1`, to represent greater- or lesser-ness. However, **does this actually happen**?

This would make writing code like

```
match String.compare key new_key with
  | 1  -> Node (left,                insert new_key right, key)
  | -1 -> Node (insert new_key left, right,                key)
  | _  -> Node (left,                right,                key)
```

much more difficult (using `when`, probably?).

I'm particularly interested in [`String.compare`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.03/libref/String.html#VALcompare). Having a look at [its implementation](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/4.03.0/stdlib/string.ml#L127), it just forwards to [`Pervasives.compare`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/4.03.0/stdlib/pervasives.ml#L62), which in turn is implemented natively using `external`. No idea what it does.

Comment: I just started learning OCaml too. It's really cool to see you posting on this tag ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm wondering why one should not use the wrapper @kne proposed directly. Your code would become:

```
match String.compare key new_key with
  | 0             -> Node (left, right, key)
  | x when x > 0  -> Node (left, insert new_key right, key)
  | _ (* x < 0*)  -> Node (insert new_key left, right, key)
```

That saves the function call and is not significantly longer than the -1 / 0 / 1 approach. Apart from that, compare is often provided by the user (see e.g. [Set.OrderedType](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.OrderedType.html)), where the constraint may be violated anyway.

Comment: Yes, that would be my solution of choice, but I wondered whether this is idiomatic? Is this construct used in enterprise ocaml projects?

Comment: I'm not programming enterprise level ocaml, but pattern matching via when is quite common.

Answer (score 6):

An answer by yourself shows that no other values can be returned *in the current implementation*. I would be very careful, though, to rely on that. As long as `compare` is not *documented* as being three-valued, future versions of OCaml may change that behaviour.

[EDIT, answering a comment] In order to avoid clumsy case distinctions (as hinted in your original question), you can wrap `compare` into a function that returns a three-values type like so:

```
type comparison = Less | Equal | More

let my_compare a b = match compare a b with
| 0 -> Equal
| c when c>0 -> More
| _ -> Less
```

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. So how would an idiomatic three-way comparison look in Ocaml?

Comment: Why isn't there such a `comparison` type in the standard library?

Answer (score 4):

> Does this actually happen?

No.

> `Pervasives.compare` is implemented natively using `external`.

I think this refers to [`compare.c`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/4.03.0/byterun/compare.c), which does implement the [`string` case](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/4.03.0/byterun/compare.c#L162-L173) using

```c
#define LESS -1
#define EQUAL 0
#define GREATER 1

mlsize_t len1 = caml_string_length(v1);
mlsize_t len2 = caml_string_length(v2);
int res = memcmp(String_val(v1), String_val(v2), len1 <= len2 ? len1 : len2);
if (res < 0) return LESS;
if (res > 0) return GREATER;
if (len1 != len2) return len1 - len2;
```

So it seems this could indeed return an arbitrary integer for strings like `compare "a" "abc"` (`-2`).

But if we try in Ocaml, this doesn't happen and just returns `-1`. Why not?
Because the [real compare function](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/4.03.0/byterun/compare.c#L269-L280) that is exposed to Ocaml code does normalise the results:

```c
CAMLprim value caml_compare(value v1, value v2)
{
  intnat res = compare_val(v1, v2, 1);
  if (res < 0)
    return Val_int(LESS);
  else if (res > 0)
    return Val_int(GREATER);
  else
    return Val_int(EQUAL);
}
```

So it indeed cannot return any `int` other than those three.